# During the Canadian Convoy Protests, what was the stated reason for freezing bank accounts?

Tags: law, canada, protests

It is common knowledge now that the Canadian Government froze a handful of bank accounts based on suspicion of funding the 2022 Convoy Protests.

When I watched [Justin Trudeau's portion](https://www.c-span.org/video/?524442-1/prime-minister-trudeau-testifies-canadian-trucker-blockade-response) of the Emergencies Act hearing, I heard he mentioned about 6 measures taken, one of which was freezing bank accounts.

However, in that hearing, I don't recall hearing any specific justification for each measure. The closest I heard was that he was told by subsidiary local authorities that they had a plan in place but that it was woefully inadequate and/or not executed.

Is there a detailed report or other official video clip that explains in detail the justification for each measure?

Comment: Not sure, but you might have to go back to the debate around passing the law that Trudeau invoked. That might require crawling through a lot of Hansard. It's more than I have time for, but feel free. https://www.ourcommons.ca/documentviewer/en/35-2/house/hansard-index

Comment: What specifically are you looking for? As you say, it was common knowledge it was for funding the 2022 convoy protests.

Comment: I see what you are saying.  Freeze the bank accounts because they were involved in funding the protests. What I am looking for is, why freezing when a different sort of sanction, like garnishment, was not sufficient?